# importError python while import exists and Pycharm recognize it

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, python-import

I'm working on a project and I'm having an error I can't fix for some reason.

the error is:

```
`from parser import WorldParser`
`ImportError: cannot import name WorldParser`
```

I'm using Pycharm, and I tried to use Pycycle to find if I have import cycles but it didn't find any and also tried manually look for cycles and I haven't found 
any.

The program structure is as follows:

```
project folder contains:
agent.py
graph.py
parser.py
simulation.py
state.py
utils.py
```

now I will elaborate on each file imports.

```
-----agent.py----

from utils import operation_dec,get_path_from_to

-----agent.py----

-----graph.py----

none

-----graph.py----

-----parser.py----

from graph import Vertex, Edge, UndirectedGraph

from state import WorldState

from utils import create_map_args, get_path_from_to

-----parser.py----

-----simulation.py----

from parser import WorldParser

from beautifultable import BeautifulTable

from agent import GreedyAgent, HumanAgent, VandalAgent

from state import WorldState

from utils import InfoObject

-----simulation.py----

-----state.py----

from beautifultable import BeautifulTable

-----state.py----

-----utils.py----

from heapq import *

-----utils.py----
```

any help is appreciated,thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your import statement from

```
from graph import Vertex, Edge, UndirectedGraph
from state import WorldState
from utils import create_map_args, get_path_from_to
```

to the following:

```
from .graph import Vertex, Edge, UndirectedGraph
from .state import WorldState
from .utils import create_map_args, get_path_from_to
```

when you are referring a module that is in the same directory. The dot tells Python that the import is from another module within the same directory / package. If you leave the dot off the import statement, Python thinks you are referring to a global package instead of a local one. Take a look at Python's official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for a more detailed explanation.

edit:
I forgot to mention you should add a `__init__.py` file in the directory to indicate to Python that the directory is a Python package.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help but I didn't create any package in this project. so now im getting an error that I'm using the dot notation without a package

Comment: I updated my answer to include adding a `__init__.py` module to the directory to indicate to Python that the directory is a Python package. This should fix your new error.